# jQuery scrollTop animation with overflow auto/scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ipad

On our webapp (http://videonot.es) we would like to add navigation link in the top navbar.
To fix our background on ipad we had to add overflow:scroll which is preventing the jQuery scrollTop animation to work.

How can we either fix the background on iPad in another way / make this animation work?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick win would be to swap out the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` and instead use a little Javascript like [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) to fix your background image. iOS and position:fixed is usually a world of hurt in my experience.